# Creating a file association icon in Ubuntu with xdgutils

Tags: linux, ubuntu, icons, file-association, xdgutils

I am using the [xdg](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-mime.html) utility to attempt to associate a image with a file association.

I have ran this command and the equivalent for 48,64 and 128 sizes, none of them seem to have an effect.

> xdg-icon-resource install --context mimetypes --size 256 image-256.png text-abc

Any ideas?

This is incredibly lame - but I have managed to get this working once, I had run the above command, then I changed the network bridge on my virtual machine from wireless to wired, and this somehow had a knock on effect to changing the ubuntu theme (the window headers changed from the usual orange to blue) and all the 'abc' files I had on the desktop had the image I've specified.

Answer (score 1):

Install and try assogiate. It is much more easier.

Comment: Update: Assogiate no longer seems to be available. Too bad, it was an amazing little tool.